# JMS MQ, XML tags in property header converted into entities

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jms, ibm-mq

I have an application based on Websphere and MQ, which expects in the JMS message headers a property which has an XML as value.

```
test="<any_value></any_value>"
```

This works ok on a messaging system like Sibus, but on MQ, it turns out like:

```
<test>&lt;any_value&gt; &lt;/any_value&gt;</test>
```

and the consumer complains that is not able to find the property or more probably to parse the content.
I am not in control of the design and I know that such should be part of the body itself rather than the header. I wonder if someone else faced the same issue or there's a solution to leave the XML tags as they are.
Thanks

Comment: To clarify... if a JMS Message (text, bytes, object etc? or anytype) has a String Property set on it that is XML, when received this is modified as shown?  

What versions of MQ JMS Clients are on either side, and what version is the QueueManager itself?

Comment: MQ server is v7.5, while the client used by WAS is 7.1.0.2.
Both producer and consumer are on the same cell, so they use the same connection. Both also the set the property as String.

Comment: As an update I have tried this locally and can't reproduce it; the behavior isn't as expected therefore I would suggest a formal problem report to IBM Service.

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible to insert unmodified XML into the property then it would be possible to include the closing property tags and then insert arbitrary properties into the system folders.  So, without knowing how it works in the code, one must assume that the entities are properly converted as the value is placed into the message.  In other words, assume that both MQ and SIBus store the data with the XML special characters converted to entities.

If that is the case, then there are a couple of possibilities.  The most likely one being that of the two IBM products, only one properly decodes the entities as the property value is read back out.

With that in mind, the only answer I have to offer is to open a PMR and *be sure to include the information that it works as expected with SIBus and fails with MQ*.  If you describe just the MQ behavior in the PMR, you are likely to get back "working as designed" with a note telling you to parse the entities in your code.  But if you point out that the same function exhibits two different behaviors in two IBM products that implement the same JMS specification then you are more likely to receive an answer that reconciles the two different behaviors and some method or fix for the one that is broken.

With luck, that fix will make MQ work like SIBus and not the other way around. But anything is possible.